# How to set up usernames from email of all users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

I would like to create rake task to set the username of all users' without a username to the part before the '@' in their email address. So if my email is test@email.eu, my username should become test. If it's not available, prepend it by a number (1).

So i have problem witch checking uniqness of username. Code below isn`t working after second loop ex: when i have three emails: test@smt.com, test@smt.pl, test@oo.com username for test@oo.com will be empty.

I have of course uniqness validation for username in User model.

```
desc "Set username of all users wihout a username"
task set_username_of_all_users: :environment do
  users_without_username = User.where(:username => ["", nil])
  users_without_username.each do |user|
    username = user.email.split('@').first
    users = User.where(:username => username)
    if users.blank?
      user.username = username
      user.save
    else
      users.each_with_index do |u, index|
        pre = (index + 1).to_s
        u.username = username.insert(0, pre)
        u.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Other ideas are in Gist: https://gist.github.com/3067635#comments

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the full email address as a username? Surely that guarantees uniqueness.

Comment: yes this is in specification of my application, it will be used in other model as index key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple while loop for checking the username:

```
users_without_username = User.where{ :username => nil }
users_without_username.each do |user|
  email_part = user.email.split('@').first
  user.username = email_part
  prefix = 1
  while user.invalid?
    # add and increment prefix until a valid name is found
    user.username = prefix.to_s + email_part
    prefix += 1
  end
  user.save
end
```

However, it might be a better approach to ask the user to enter a username upon next login.

Comment: this is only for old users which are in database wihout username

Comment: @regedarek, what do you mean? Did you try this solution? It does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: I think this is answer for question which has been deleted. But of course this is my solution. Thanks. I only changed ```prefix``` to ```prefix.to_s```

Comment: Hmm, but there is a problem with prefix: when I have username ```test``` after second loop i get ```21test``` but I would like to get ```2test```

Comment: @regedarek `insert` modifies the string, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your code correct, you are changing the username of existing users in the else branch? that does not look as if it's a good idea.

you should also use a real finder to select your users that don't have a username. otherwise you will load all the users before selecting on them.

i don't know if it "matches your requirements" but you could just put a random number to the username so that you do not have the problem of duplicates.

another thing that you can use is rubys retry mechanism. just let active-record raise an error and retry with a changed username.

```
begin
   do_something # exception raised
rescue
   # handles error
   retry  # restart from beginning
end
```

Comment: i`m not changing username, I do it only for users without username

Answer (score 0):

In your query `User.find_by_username(username)`, you only expect 1 record to be provided. So you don't need any `each`. You should add your index in another way.

Comment: Yes of course i changed it to ```User.where{ :username => nil }```